# Why did the mac address of bond changed on CentOS7 after reboot

Tags: centos, mac-address, bonding, lacp

I have two interfaces bonded together in LACP mode (mode=4 <=> 802.3ad) in `bond0` :

The mac address of `bond0`before reboot :

```bash
$ cat /sys/class/net/bond0/address
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bf
```

The mac address of `bond0`after reboot :

```bash
$ cat /sys/class/net/bond0/address
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bd
```

Here is some information about the network configuration :

```bash
$ ip -o l | grep state.UP
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ grep BONDING_OPTS= /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1"
$ egrep "(MASTER|SLAVE)=" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em?
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1:MASTER=bond0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1:SLAVE=yes
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em2:MASTER=bond0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em2:SLAVE=yes
$ egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
[logging]
```

Why did the mac address of `bond0` change ?

Comment: FYI: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70215

Comment: @K-att- I had already checked this one, down below it says :
`Note: Red Hat does not support assigning a permanent MAC address to bond interfaces in active-backup mode with the fail_over_mac option set to follow or active.` I don't use the `active-backup` mode, I use the `802.ad` (LACP) mode.

Comment: The mac address created "on the fly" via script. If you want permanent MAC address, you need to specify it.

Comment: @K-att- It's a good workaround but I'd like to know/understand : What triggered that mac address change ?

Comment: Just hint: the arp table maybe? The script try to create the unique mac address. It's not change. The mac address recreated every time.

Comment: @K-att- Yes but we have 22 servers that might have potentially the same problem. I need to understand what happened ? What do you mean by the `arp table maybe`, can you tell me more about it ?

Comment: Sorry, I did remember the VM's ethernet address... `For other configurations, if not explicitly configured (with
ifconfig or ip link), the MAC address of the bonding device is taken from
its first slave device.  This MAC address is then passed to all following
slaves and remains persistent (even if the first slave is removed) until
the bonding device is brought down or reconfigured.`
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt 
=> the first slave changed.

Comment: @K-att- Thanks, now the question comes to `Why did em1 had its mac address changed ?`

Answer (score 1):

Considering the last octet is only a couple off, it's most likely that the two NICs `em1` and `em2` are on the same card, and the bond has picked up the MAC from the other NIC.

The bond will pick up the MAC address from the first NIC which joins the bond.

However, **the order in which NICs enumerate is not deterministic**.

One boot, NIC `em1` with MAC ending `bd` might join the bond first, so the bond picks up MAC ending `bd`.

Another boot, NIC `em2` with MAC ending `bf` might join the bond first, so the bond picks up MAC ending `bf`.

That's just how hardware enumeration works.

More recent NetworkManager has a feature where it joins child devices to a parent device in a specific order to solve this exact problem, so move to RHEL9 (which you can get [for free](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/faqs-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux)) or Rocky/Alma 9 if you prefer those.

---

Another possible option is that you're forcing the NICs to have the names `em1` and `em2` despite those being reserved names that systemd expects to be able to use. If you are doing this, don't. It doesn't work.

Let systemd name devices how it wants, or move to manual names which the kernel and systemd don't expect to use. You might use `netX` or similar.